# Enable Einstein Bots in the Developer org

Tags: community, einstein-analytics, chat

I am not getting the option to enable the Einstein bot in the developer org following the steps mentioned in the trailhead[https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/build-an-einstein-bot/set-up-an-einstein-bot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the **salesforce** to enable it.

Comment: Its not displaying in the salesforce classic. the option to enable Einstein bolt is only available in the lightning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After I enabled "Chat", It worked out with enabling Einstein Bots in the Developer org.
Please reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bots_service_enable.htm&type=5